# An USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget is in conflict with internet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have a device that communicates with a laptop computer through a "USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget" driver. It uses a fixed IP address (192.168.1.100) for its connection. In one case, this is what I experienced and I do not know how to tackle this problem.

If the laptop in question is already connected to the internet, say via Zoom, when I connect my device to it, it would not start. But if I connect my device to the laptop before starting, say a browser, or Zoom, to connect to the internet, my device now works but the computer cannot connect to the internet! The IT person in charge of this computer reported that

> "We don’t use the 192.168.1.x subnet at our place so the issue
> shouldn’t be an IP conflict. I had our network guys check to see if
> they could detect a rogue DHCP server and they couldn’t see anything
> either. I also ran a scan of the whole subnet and didn’t detect
> anything in that range either. The laptop itself has an IP address of
> 10.1.xxx.yyy which was assigned via DHCP."

My application needs to connect to an internal computer network to access a database as well, therefore, I need both my device and the network connection to work with this laptop. So what is the problem? Could this be a Firewall issue? Is it possible that somehow the Windows' (Win 10) or a special Firewall forbids this scenario?

Thank you.

(I posted this question on Stackoverflow. I was asked to post here! I hope it is OK)

Comment: " Is it possible that somehow the Windows 10 forbids this scenario?" - No

Comment: did you find the solution for it?